# Android - Deep-link to open link in Chrome

Tags: php, android, html, google-chrome

I want to add a deep-link which opens the url in chrome on a website. Before I was using this one and it was working;

```
header("Location: intent://www.google.com".$id."#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end");
```

Now it doesn't work (opens a pop-up asking user to select browser asking Samsung Browser or Chrome)

What is the correct way to deep-link a url for chrome ?

Comment: This looks like it might be useful: https://doordash.engineering/2022/01/25/your-deep-links-might-be-broken-web-intents-and-android-12/ (I'm not affiliated with the company.) Also, this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66708374/deep-linking-not-working-in-chrome-mobile-browser, but I'm not sure whether the answers are still current or not.